# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{5^x-3^x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Problem: Evaluate

> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{5^x-3^x}{x}$$

This would become quite easy if I could apply L'Hopital's Rule (the answer I got was $\ln(5)-\ln(3)$). However, I'm supposed to solve it without L'Hopital's Rule. 
I thought of taking the logarithm of the Numerator and the Denominator, but was unable to proceed further.
 
Any help on this question would be truly appreciated. Many thanks!$$$$
Cheers!

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: Please, do not use \dfrac in the titles. And title should not consist only of LaTeX. See: [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles(http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles)

Comment: Alright Sir. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HINT : Let $f(x)=5^x-3^x$. Then, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{5^x-3^x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}.$$

Comment: Sorry Sir, I couldn't quite understand . Could you please elaborate a bit more, Sir?

Comment: I just noticed the similarity to $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}=nx^{n-1}$

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)$.

Comment: Alright, thanks Sir.

Comment: IMO, this is just an instance of L'Hospital for $f(x)/x\to f'(x)/1$.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how you do it using standard limit.

$$L=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{(5^x-1)-(3^x-1)}{x}$$

$$L=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{(5^x-1)}{x}-\frac{(3^x-1)}{x}$$

---

Lemma:

$$P=\lim_\limits{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a$$

Put $a^x-1=t$ so that $x=\log_a{(1+t)}$ and notice that as $x\to 0$$\implies$ $a \to 0$

$$P=\lim_\limits{a\to 0}\frac{t}{\log_a(1+t)}=\lim_\limits{a\to 0}\frac{1}{\log_a(1+t)^{1/t}}=\frac{1}{\log_ae}=\ln a$$

---

Using this result, the required limit .

$L=\ln5-\ln 3$

Answer (score 3):

If you know

$${\mathrm e}^{k\,x}=1 + k\,x+{\mathcal{O}}(x^2),$$

you can use

$$a^x={\mathrm e}^{x\log(a)}$$

to see that

$$\dfrac{a^x-b^x}{x}=\log(a)-\log(b)+{\mathcal{O}}(x).$$

Comment: Sir, I don't know that $O$ symbol you wrote. Please could you tell me what it is?

Comment: @BetterWorld: My Dear Lord, havet a look at [thus linkus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).